# key mapping error, only with my app

Tags: android, bluetooth, mapping, headset

my app is supposed to handle bluetooth buttons. However, when I press the "next" button on a bluetooth device, or from the original wired headset, I got this in Logcat :
bluetooth device :

```
11-29 13:36:48.757: W/KeyCharacterMap(8730): Can't open keycharmap file
11-29 13:36:48.757: W/KeyCharacterMap(8730): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/AVRCP.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65540.devname='AVRCP'
11-29 13:36:48.757: W/KeyCharacterMap(8730): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

original wired headset (samsung):

```
12-03 12:37:42.570: W/KeyCharacterMap(9210): Can't open keycharmap file
12-03 12:37:42.570: W/KeyCharacterMap(9210): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/bcm_headset.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65536.devname='bcm_headset'
12-03 12:37:42.570: W/KeyCharacterMap(9210): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

I though it may be due to a device problem (I'm debugging with a Galaxy Y under 2.3.6), but when doing the same test running Winamp, I got this :

```
11-29 13:35:30.593: I/BTL-BTAPP_AV(3510): btui_av_callback(BTA_AV_REMOTE_CMD_EVT  rc_id: x4c key_state: 0)
11-29 13:35:30.593: V/BTL-BTAPP_RC(3510): +btapp_rc_handler
11-29 13:35:30.593: D/BTL-BTAPP_RC(3510): AVRCP: BACKWARD pressed
11-29 13:35:30.593: D/BTL_CFG(3510): btl_cfg_get_avrcp_pass_thru_status: service.brcm.bt.avrcp_pass_thru=1
11-29 13:35:30.593: I/BTL-BTAPP_RC(3510): AVRCP: Send key 165 (1) fd=32
11-29 13:35:30.593: D/InputReader(1476): Input event: value=1
11-29 13:35:30.593: I/InputDispatcher(1476): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0, channel '40897a08 com.nullsoft.winamp/com.nullsoft.winamp.TrackBrowserActivity (server)'
```

and the corresponding action is trigerred...

Can I map the key myself ? How ?
Am I supposed to do that ?

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Please explain what kind of a bluetooth device you are using.

Comment: is that making any difference ? it's a loudspeaker Satechi ST-66BTA

Answer (score 1):

I am not confronted with similar problems. But after searching I found two really interesting links which may be helpful for you.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/FJREhX8eX9k

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695936

Comment: yeah I know both links, and both seems to point on device's related problem... that's why I've posted logs with 2 different apps running on the same device, meaning the mapping can somehow be handle by the app.
thank you for time anyway =)